# Space of measures is weak-* Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

If $X$ is a topological space which is hereditarily Lindelöf and completely regular, then the space of finite signed measures on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, endowed with the weak-* topology, is Hausdorff. This is because we just need to check that l.s.c. functions separate measures (for then open sets certainly separate measures) and we can approximate bounded l.s.c. functions by continuous bounded functions thanks to complete regularity, and countable families such functions are sufficient thanks to hereditary Lindelöfness.

According to Varadarajan, when X is a completely regular Hausdorff space, the space of finite signed measures is still Hausdorff for the weak-* topology. (See American Math. Soc. Trans. 109 (1963) p. 193.)

I can't see why this is true. Could you explain?